# How to make outline to the top?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('outline_collapsed_test.xlsx')
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet('Outlined Rows')

worksheet1.set_row(2, None, None, {'level': 2})
worksheet1.set_row(3, None, None, {'level': 2})
worksheet1.set_row(4, None, None, {'level': 2})
worksheet1.set_row(5, None, None, {'level': 1})

worksheet1.set_row(6, None, None, {'level': 2})
worksheet1.set_row(7, None, None, {'level': 2})
worksheet1.set_row(8, None, None, {'level': 2})
worksheet1.set_row(9, None, None, {'level': 1})

workbook.close()
```

this code place symbol '+' on the bottom. How to move it to the top? like this [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.outlineproperties.aspx

```
worksheet1.outline_settings(outline_below = 0)
```

Comment: Correct. And here is a link to the [`outline_settings()`](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/worksheet.html#outline_settings) section of the XlsxWriter documentation.